# How can I slow down jQuery Mobile transition?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I looked it up on jQuery Mobile API

but it appears what I can do is, create my own transition

Is there some kind of an attribute I can add inside the HTML5 or CSS3 or JavaScript to "slow down" the transitions?

Thank you StackOverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the CSS

```
.in, .out {
-webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 100ms;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, does it overwrite the existing CSS?  Or I should modify the jQuery mobile CSS itself?

Comment: I wouldnt edit the jquery mobile css.  I would add it to your own file, which will overwrite the jquery mobile css, provided that the link to your css file is placed below the jquery css file in your html.